# jquery next() on element that was just added

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's what I'm trying to have happen:

- someone enters text into an input field
- when they hit `ENTER` on their keyboard, it adds an input field AFTER the current input field using the `after()` function, then it focuses that input field so they can continue typing and do this over and over

heres my code which is not working:

```
$('.table-todo input[type=text]').live('keypress', function (e) {   
    if (e.which == 13) 
    {
        $parent = $(this).parent('.field');     
        $.get('projects-add-task.php?show_delete=yes', function (data) { $parent.after(data); }, 'html');
        $(this).next('input[type=text]').focus();
    }
});
```

heres the contents of `projects-add-task.php`:

```
<div class="field">
<input type="text" name="task[]" />
<a href="#" title="Add Task Below" class="todo-add"><img src="images/icon-todo-add.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='images/icon-todo-add-h.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icon-todo-add.png'" /></a>
<?php if ($_GET['show_delete'] == 'yes') { ?>
<a href="#" title="Delete This Task" class="todo-delete"><img src="images/icon-todo-delete.png" alt="" onmouseover="this.src='images/icon-todo-delete-h.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/icon-todo-delete.png'" /></a>
<?php } else { ?>
<img src="images/icon-todo-delete-o.png" alt="" />
<?php } ?>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

its just not focusing the input that was added via `$.get` and i cant figure out how to fix it. it is adding the next input field to the page fine, but its not focusing it.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ and link to it? It's easier for people to help out if they can run the code themselves.

Comment: Shouldn't `$(this).next('input[type=text]').focus();` be `$parent.next('input[type=text]').focus();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    $parent = $(this).parent('.field');    
    $this = $(this);
    $.get('projects-add-task.php?show_delete=yes', function (data) { 
        $parent.after(data); 
        $parent.next().children('input[type=text]').focus();
    }, 'html');
```

The problem is that the next input element is not actually created when `$(this).next('input[type=text]').focus();` is executed because you are using an AJAX call to create it. Also you need the parent's next element.

Comment: Your code does not work. I know thats the issue, I need to make the new element `live` before I call the `next()` function, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Edited. You were checking for this element's next but it's supposed to be parent's next element actually...